# ASP File Upload control uploads only one file while trying to upload multiple files

Tags: .net, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using the below code. But for some reason only one file is uploading.

------.aspx code

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />

 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label">
```

------.cs code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(@"D:\DesignFilesLocaion\" + FileUpload1.FileName);


            }
            Label2.Text = string.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Please select file";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

postedFile.SaveAs(@"D:\DesignFilesLocaion\" + FileUpload1.FileName);

To

postedFile.SaveAs(@"D:\DesignFilesLocaion\" + postedFile.FileName);